# Do we say the "chocolate snickers wrapper or packet or package or sachet"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

This is the most confusing term

In the oxford dictionary, they distinguish between "packet", "package" and "sachet" in American and British English.

[image: images of a "stick of" butter; “packet of” gum/biscuits/cookies/candy/chips (UK crisps) and]

[image: two sachets one of ketchup, and one of sugar]

**Note**: the former in these pictures is in British English and the latter is in American English.

I am sure most of you might know **snicker**

[image: image of a chocolate snickers bar]

I am not sure if we say "**I held the chocolate by its wrapper or packet or package or sachet**"?

Comment: The candy is always called "Snickers"; it's a proper name, so it's always capitalized, and always plural.

Comment: …and some of us are old enough to remember when it was still called Marathon ;)) Snickers always sounds like someone is laughing at it. Never worked for me as a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, individual chocolate bars are described as having a ***wrapper*** whether it is vacuum-sealed, sealed with glue or just loosely wrapped. We describe such items as being *individually wrapped*.

A 'packet' tends to contain more than one item, such as a packet of crisps, biscuits, or mints.

A 'sachet' tends to contain an uncountable substance, such as sugar or sauce.

Comment: You are speaking for British English, aren't you?

Comment: @Tom yes I'm a native British English speaker. I'm aware of differences in US English in some of the packaging types in your image, but none that apply to the focus of your question which I understand to be the Snickers bar. Also, some differences exist because of different ways of packaging things rather than having different names for the same thing. In the UK, we don't sell butter in a long stick-shape so we don't say 'a stick of butter'. If we did sell it in that shape, we might!

Comment: American English would also use "wrapper" for a Snickers bar. (Incidentally, we would call it "a Snickers bar," not "a chocolate" or "a snicker.")